# Discrete random variable with $f(x)=c(2x-1)$

Tags: summation, random-variables

I feel really stupid because I don't understand this example at the start of my textbook. The chapter is discrete random variables and it starts out with this example with no explanation. I understand the rule that $\sum f(x)=1$ so I can see why there is a $1$ at the front of this equation. I don't understand how the equation went from $\sum (2x-1)$ to $2\sum x-12$. And the step after that - are they following a formula there? I'm having trouble finding information on the internet that explains this type of problem. Thank you in advance.

$$f(x)=c(2x-1) \text{ for } x=1,2,\dots,12$$

$$1=c\sum_{x=1}^{12} (2x-1)=c\left[2\sum_{x=1}^{12} x-12\right]=c\left[\frac{2(12)(13)}{2}-12\right]=c(12)^2$$

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, I found the rules:

$ \displaystyle{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} c  } = cn$

$ \displaystyle{ \sum_{i=1}^{n} i 
= { n(n+1) \over 2 } } $

So, $\displaystyle c\sum_{x=1}^{12} (2x-1)=c[2\sum_{x=1}^{12} x-\sum_{x=1}^{12}1]=c[2\sum_{x=1}^{12} x-(1)(12)]$
(by the first rule)

And the rest is easy following the second rule.

Answer (score 1):

$$\displaystyle 1=c\sum_{x=1}^{12} (2x-1)=c[2\sum_{x=1}^{12} x-12]=c[\frac{2(12)(13)}{2}-12]=c(12)^2$$

Your question is why is $$\sum_{x=1}^{12}1=12$$  This is simply adding 1 - 12 times.  On the other and $$\sum_{x=1}^{12} x$$ is sum of x taking the values 1 to 12 = $1+2+3+\cdots+12$ which utilizes the sum of an n consecutive integers $1+2+3+\cdots+n$ = n(n+1)/2.

Comment: The (2x-1) I would have factorized to 2(x-1/2) and then removed the 2 to the outside leaving (x-.5) after sigma. Is that incorrect?

Comment: Thanks for the second part - the n(n+1)/2 formula makes perfect sense.

Comment: You are welcome